# Current Guide on Safely Selecting from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, mysqli

I am sure this is already out there, but can anyone recommend the correct way to safely select data from MySQL database using PHP? I am using mysqli prepared statements, but wasn't sure if there is anything else I should be doing to make it safer.

Comment: 1. Use PDO, not mysqli. 2. There are cases when prepared statements are of no help. Here is a guide I wrote to cover all the cases: [The only proper PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: @YourCommonSense The difference is named parameters, right? What if you just cannot get to grips with OOP?

Comment: @Strawberry [the difference is enormous](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison). While regarding OOP, there is Object programming and object syntax. The latter is comprehensible by a 5-year old.